# JS anonymous function invocation syntax

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two:

```
(function () {
    alert('something');
})();​  # invocation parens after the wrapping parens
```

and

```
(function () {
    alert('something');
}());  # invocation parens inside the wrapping parens
```

—both give me the same result: alerting "something".

Comment: There's no functional difference. The parentheses are needed for making the function an expression, but it's irrelevant where they close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference. Both will do exactly the same thing (invoke the anonymous function expression).

The parentheses around the anonymous function are simply there to ensure the function is parsed as an *expression* rather than a declaration (which is important because a declaration can't be invoked). You may also see other operators used to the same effect. For example:

```
// All three of the following have the same effect:

!function () {
    alert('something');
}();​

+function () {
    alert('something');
}();​

(function () {
    alert('something');
}());​
```

Note that if you use a static analysis tool like JSLint [it may complain](http://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function/) about the first form in your question (with the invoking parentheses outside the grouping operator). The reason for this is that some people consider the second form easier to understand.

Comment: I never knew you could also use `!` or `+` for that. Good info.

Comment: you can use pretty much any operator, that's why `something = function () {} ();` will work as well

Comment: @Cerbus, can use the bitwise operators, too: `~function(){}();` is used from time to time. Anything that makes a function declaration part of a statement (and thus making the function declaration part of an expression) works: `var ignoreMe = function(){}();` works just as well. But that's what this explains very clearly: +1 for that

Comment: @ShlomiSasson - `!` is the "logical not" operator, which will negate the return value of the function. `+` in this context is the unary plus operator which will convert the return value of the function into a number.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, so what you mean is that the example above is just use the operators as a "trick" to make the example work? (since making  function () {alert('something');}();​ alone thrown an error)

Comment: But + and () _are_ different from ! since the former behave differently in case of ASI (automatic semicolon insertion). If the previous code does not end the statement/expression, then both () and + will trigger the two expressions to be merged, + adding them up, () invoking the first expression with the 2nd expression as argument). That's why some code uses the ! operator, especially when writing semicolon-free code, to make sure no matter what the preceding code, it will not be affected by the function call.

Answer (score 3):

JSLint treats the `})();` invocation as *"wrong"*. The function definition *and* invocation are part of a single expression. It's quite logical for that reason alone that the invocation is part of the expression itself.

In essence, that's just a matter of personal preference. Personally, I find

```
(function(elem)
{
})(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

Easier to read than

```
(function(elem)
{
}(document.getElementById('foo')));
```

but then again, any editor with syntax highlighting nullifies that argument. 
Bottom line: use the one you feel most comfortable with, and let jslint nag about it, Douglas Crockford is an authority when it comes to JS, but that doesn't mean we all have to blindly copy his style/reasoning

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping something into parentheses (in JS) forces the interpreter to treat it as an expression.

In the first case you force the interpreter to treat the function as an expression, then the interpreter evaluates that, concludes it's a function an then looks further: `()`, so it invokes the function.

In the second case you force the interpreter to treat the invoking parens as an expression too, so the result of the function call would be the result of the expression, if it would return something (else it would be undefined - thanks Elias van Ootegem).

Comment: thanks! so there is a difference (not like some told above) between the both - just in the return value, i think it's important to know.. :) TA.

Comment: @ShlomiSasson - There is a difference in what will be returned by the *grouping operator*. It will either return an anonymous function (which is then invoked immediately) or the return value of that function (since it's been invoked immediately while evaluating the group). Therefore there is no functional difference between the two (you can try this by assigning the result of the expression to a variable and then checking its value).

Comment: The result of a function call is never `void` in JS, if there's no explicit `return` statement, the function will return `undefined`. Also, it looks as if you _do_ say that there's a difference in the way both notations are evaluated, and that this distinction is reflected in the value in which the expressions are resolved, which isn't the case: `(function(){}())`<-- in order for JS to know what to invoke, the function declaration has to be evaluated separatly

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it returns `undefined`, I meant that but forgot the word... But I meant that this distinction is reflected in the result of the expression within the parentheses. @EliasVanOotegem

Comment: @11684: ow, now I see what you mean and of course you're right about the resulting value of the _grouped expressions_, I thought you meant that the resulting value of the entire statement would differ.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that, although I must admit I wasn't very clear about that. @EliasVanOotegem